# Why are Excel Array formulas slow?

Tags: arrays, excel

I have read in many places on the web that one of the downsides of using array formulas is that they are slow (and that using intermediate helper columns can speed things up).

The general explanation given is that they are performing a lot of work. They are, but the helper formulas must surely also be reproducing the same amount of work spread across different cells.

I would like to understand in a little more detail:

1. **Why** array formulas are slow?
2. What situations might it not be so?

Comment: As the source code for Excel is not viewable, I imagine this is going to generate more opinion than anything else - but I'd guess at array formulas using loops in the source code which is always going to be more overhead.

Comment: Have you Googled for this question? There are any number of reasons, one of which being how long the formula is.  [This page](http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/03/20/optimize-speedup-excel-formulas/) goes over formula optimization, which also includes why they may be slow.   [Here's another good page](http://www.decisionmodels.com/optspeedj.htm) as well. This is a pretty broad question for SO, which is generally for Code review.  This is also going to be pretty subjective...(edit: and a [third page](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/Arrays.htm))

Comment: @MacroMan loops within underlying source code are very often performant. For example, writing interpreted python it is recommended to use array formulas to speed up your computations BECAUSE they are using pre-compiled C loops.

Comment: @Sam my knowledge of C really isn't that great so I have nothing to come back wth on that, but interesting to know nontheless +1

Answer (score 5):

Let's have a concrete example:

[image]

Formulas:

in `D2:E11`:

```
=IF($A2=D$1,$B2)
```

in `D12` and `E12`:

```
=SUM(D2:D11)
```

in `D13` and `E13`:

```
{=SUM(IF($A$2:$A$11=D$1,$B$2:$B$11))}
```

as an array formula confirmed with [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter]

in `D14` and `E14`:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$11,D$1,$B$2:$B$11)
```

So what happens if something changes in `A2:B11`?

In the helper columns only those formulas needs to recalculate which refers to the cells which have actually changed. And of course the sums in `D12` and `E12` must be recalculated. But this is exactly wherefore Excel was developed. So the program is probably optimized to do exactly this very performant.

The array formula must be fully recalculated, independent of which cells have actually changed. That are 10 `IF` functions and the `SUM` after each change in `A2:B11`. And there is nothing optimized. The array context causes only the `IF`function, which per default expect one criteria and one value_if_the_criteria_is_true, to perform multiple times for each criteria in the criteria array and provide a results array, which is then summed by `SUM`.

The `SUMIF` also must be fully recalculated. But this will be done with the precompiled function `SUMIF` which is optimized to do so. That function not simply calls the `IF` function 10 times, as the array formula does.

So if it comes to performance, the solution with helper columns will be the best, then comes `SUMIF` and the array formula is surely the solution with lowest performance.

But of course the performance difference will only noticeable if either there are much data cells which influence the formulas or if there are much array formulas in the sheet. So if one needs using array formulas, then those should not take whole columns or rows as arrays and one should not put thousands of array formulas in the sheet.