# how many times a value occurred consecutively in a column- excel

Tags: excel, function, countif

I have been searching for a while and can't seem to find an answer so here I am posting hoping someone might help.
I am trying to find how many times a value occurred consecutively in a column.
For example, how many time did the word " Negative" occur 4 time consecutively in the column. 
How many times did it occur 5 times in a row ( I mean by in a row,one after another) 
I have attached a picture
Thank you [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmqAi.png)

Comment: A very simple approach will be to check 5 consecutive rows using IF & AND in in the next column and adding this column. Something like `IF(AND(B1="Negative",B2="Negative",B3="Negative",B4="Negative"),1,0))`

Comment: Sure that makes sense for the first 5,6 numbers but what if I have 1000 numbers then I cant use this for all of them..

Comment: Sure you can. unless you are trying to get number of 1000 consecutive negatives. Anyways, i have posted another approach. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your datais in column B. In column C enter this formula as an array

```
SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISERROR(OFFSET(B7,0,0,$C$1,1)),0,IF(OFFSET(B7,0,0,$C$1,1)="Negative",1,0)))=$C$1
```

where $C$1 has the value of number of consecutive "Negative"s to be found. To enter the  formula as an array, enter the formula in the cell, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. You can then drag this all the way down.

us this formula in another cell to get the number of occurences of consecutive Negatives

```
=COUNTIF(C2:C1088,TRUE)
```

Here is a [Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sIiivMyi6f34ZNqcMAhpVhh9GKbha18yb5HsUXF5g_g/edit?usp=sharing) with Demo

Comment: My experience with array formula in Microsoft Excel is not very good... if you have a lot of data, the calculation will slow to a crawl, in that case using VBA or splitting the calculation using helper columns might be a better choice. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148716/why-are-excel-array-formulas-slow)