# Is Array Formula (Dynamic Array) slower than copying the formulas in all cells with relative reference?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, dynamic-arrays

## Context.

- My question is related to both Google-Sheet and Microsoft Excel.
- Dynamic Array Formula's are newly added to Excel, but the concept of array formula is old. But my question is related to the newly added Dynamic Array Formula's in Excel's Context.

## Question

Both in Excel and in Google-Sheets, I can refer to another column in two ways (Screenshot below).

1. Using a direct reference(`=$D2`) to the adjacent cell and dragging the formula to all cells below in same column
2. Using a Dynamic Array Formula(`=D2:D5`)

So the Question is, which of these formula's is recommended? And how does each formula impact the speed of the file/sheet based on the amount of data.

***Note:*** The reason that I'm asking this question in Stack-Overflow is because it involves Software performance.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148716/why-are-excel-array-formulas-slow) already asked in SO, but

1. That question is related to the old Array Formula's not Dynamic Arrays.
2. It was asked and answered 4 years back and before the new features were added in Excel. These new features have performance improvements

[image: Dynamic Array Performance]

## My Opinion

From what I have tried, I did not see any difference when I used either of these options. I tried this in a Google sheet with Import ranges from other sheet of roughly 300,000 cells - 5000 Rows and 60 Columns. And in this file, there was some lag but it's the same with Dynamic array and formula's. But i'm not sure if this is a big enough file to visually notice the difference.

Comment: Why not do some testing yourself?

Comment: @SJR, I have added my opinion from my tests in the question.

Answer (score 1):

arrayformulas are generally faster unless they are dealing with ridiculously huge arrays (10+k of rows) or very complex calculations (mmult matrixes). when dealing with small ranges there is no speed difference. in such cases, it's about efficiency - a big difference to use 1 single arrayformula for computing two columns of 1000 than using 2000 single-cell formulas in 2000 cells and waste 10+ seconds just by dragging them down.