# Extract data from sheet range based on condition (like DataFrame.loc) using VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

The problem for some of you Python coders out there is doing `DataFrame.loc[DataFrame['Name']=='John'][-1]`.

This is what I have in the spreadsheet, let's say from cell range (A1:E3).

| Name | Bio | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Loves travelling to the mountains | 11/20 |
| Joe | plays computer | 11/20 |
| John | goes to the sea a lot | 01/22 |
| Jenny | dances salsa | 02/22 |

On a separate sheet, I have 2 buttons and 2 cells

1. Add information to database (built in VBA)
2. Extract latest information to database
3. First cell allows me to enter the name such as 'John'
4. Second cell that allows me to enter the Bio (or equivalently extract the bio to)

[image]

How could I, if I type **John** and click the button to extract the bio, get the latest **Bio** (the one dated 01/22) for **John** into another cell?

Comment: IF you have Excel 365 check MAXIFS https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got an older version of Excel you may do this with SUMPRODUCT:

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--(A2:A5=G5)*C2:C5))
```

In Excel 365, you can use function MAXIFS:

> [MAXIFS
> function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883)

Comment: Is `SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--(testRange=condition)*(dataRange))` more performant than `MAX(IF(testRange=condition, dataRange))`?

Comment: @ChrisStrickland To be honest, that's an open discussion posted here before (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148716/why-are-excel-array-formulas-slow   https://superuser.com/questions/879026/whats-more-efficient-array-formulas-or-individual-formulas) but my opinion would be that array formulas allow you to do stuff than normal functions won't so recalculations needs more resources. I avoid them if I can but it's ok to use them

Comment: I just tried a million rows of random data on both and they were both pretty much instantaneous.  There might have been a tiny lag on the MAX/IF construction, but it could have been my imagination.  None of them triggered the calculation counter.  Not even sure how I would check it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I figured out a solution for anybody else looking for something similar and have closed this query.

if we set up a data array that can be used to store the table in the sheet range. Then we can loop through the data as such:

```
Dim rowCount
Dim dataArray As Variant
Dim bio

For i = 1 To rowCount
  
    If dataArray(i, 1) = Name Then
        bio = dataArray(i, 2)
    End If
Next
Sheets("Main").Range("A5") = bio
```

where **rowCount** should be the number of rows in the table, this can be specified inside a cell on the sheet, and **Name** be whatever name it is such as 'John'